# Bootstrap offset and HTML5 Canvas

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, canvas

I have a canvas that I can draw on using jQuery but I am having an issue integrating it with bootstrap. More precisely, when I put a

```
col-lg-offset-4
```

in my class, the canvas stops responding to my clicks.

Here is the Bootply:

http://www.bootply.com/QmRU7dDF58#

Notice that if you remove the offset, and then run it again, it starts working fine. Try it on Bootply.

Any help would be highly appreciated. I've been trying to fix this for too long.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `col-lg-offset-4` other than `col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4` for the class. For a quick fix.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-4">
        <div class="example" id="drawing">
            <h1>Drawing with the mouse</h1>
            <canvas></canvas>
            <button id="erase">Erase</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your code it's actually drawing on the canvas but way far to the right of it. For example if it was like so:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1">
```

You will notice this offset drawing.

Ok so how do we keep it with `<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">`? Well notice what is being offset is that `div` element and not the Canvas. So we need to adjust our drawing position based on that `div`, in other words the parent of the `canvas`. So in your code other than `this.offset` we need the parents `.left` and `.top` offset like so (and changes to get it in the middle):

```
var offsetL = $(this).parent().offset().left;
var offsetT = this.offsetTop + $(this).parent().offset().top - this.offsetLeft; 
addClick(e.pageX - offsetL, e.pageY - offsetT, true);
redraw();
```

**[Here is your working](http://www.bootply.com/sGKpoQPoMi)** code with the offset.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one issue, does `col-lg-offset-4` automatically sets `col-lg-4` for the canvas itself? What if I have multiple things in the row and want them to have columns specifically assigned?

Comment: Originally, I have an offset of 1, then a div of 3, then the canvas of 4, then another div of 3 and finally the offset of 1. How can I make sure that what I draw is on the canvas and not somewhere where it isn't visible? Thanks

Comment: It does not. One second, I'll provide a solution with both. Basically you just need to adjust how you get your mouse position in your JavaScript.

Comment: @user4052205 Ok, take a look at my updated answer for how to update the mouse drawing position based on the offset.